# Renaming files sequentially with 4 digits - .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for a solution to my problem, below the script I'm using, I found it here, changed it, it was working the way I wanted to for what I was doing but now I want to do that and I'm struggling with the answer.

Example:

```
<br>Open_university_MS221_0001.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0001-2.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0002.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0002-2.tif</br>
<br>etc.</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0001.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0002.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0003.tif</br>
<br>Open_university_MS221_0004.tif</br>
<br>etc.</br>
```

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
    set FileName=%%~nf
    set FileName=000!count!
    set FileName=!FileName:~-4!
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_+" %%g in ('dir /b /od *.tif') do ( 
        set prefix=%%g_%%h_%%i
    )
    set FileName=!prefix!_!Filename!%%~xf
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
    set /a count+=1
)
```

Comment: The code you have posted in indented poorly. Whilst that does not affect how the code works, it certainly aids in readability. Had you indented it correctly before submitting it, you'd have clearly noted that it has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Sorry about that, i edited it, thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are iterating the `*.tif` files twice. Your outer loop should be `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "*.tif"') do (` (to force alphabetic sorting), and the inner one should be `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_ eol=_" %%g in ("%%~nf") do (` (to handle the file name currently iterated by the outer loop)…

Comment: Thanks it works (almost) see my edit.

Comment: i found a solution by renaming with 5 digits then coming back to 4 but i'm sure it's not the best way or more efficient one.

Comment: Your edit Jeremy UK, which you've stated in it, is the solution, does not belong in the question area. There is an answer area for posting solutions. I have therefore returned your question to its previous incarnation.

Comment: Thanks Compo, sorry it's my first day here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of a lot of code within the loop, when you initialize the counter to `10000` before entering the loop. Then within the loop, you just use `!count:~-4!`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=10000
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_+" %%g in ('dir /b /od *.tif') do ( 
        set prefix=%%g_%%h_%%i
    )
    set /a count+=1
    set FileName=!prefix!_!count:~-4!%%~xf
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

The code could be shortened even more but at the cost of readability.

Oh - and I moved `set /a count+=1` up to avoid starting with `0000` (your example shows, you don't want that)

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look and play with your answer. if you want have a look at my edit i found a way, thanks to ashipfl too

Answer (score 1):

Working solution below, thanks to aschipfl who did show me the way and Stephan

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%i"

cd %folder%

set path=%folder:~1%
    for %%i in ("%path%") do (
        set "parent=%%~ni"
    )

set /a count=10000
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "*.tif"') do (
        set /a count+=1
        set fileName=!parent!_!count:~-4!%%~xf
        rename "%%f" "!fileName!"
)

exit /b
```

Comment: DON'T mess with the `%PATH%` variable - it tells Windows where to find its executables. Chose another name.

Comment: oh yeah, i read it somewhere else too but i don't know why, i did it, anyway thanks for the highlight, i'll change it. Now i will try to do the same but trough the subfolders do you think i need only to add a ```for /r "%folder%" %%a in (*) do (... ``` instead of the ```set path=... ```

Comment: yes, `for /r "%folder%" %%a in ...` is correct. Maybe `... in (*_*_*_*.tif) do ...` (depends on the exact format of your file names)

Comment: thanks, i'll try with it, i also did another question related to that renaming recursively. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010177/renaming-files-sequentially-trough-subfolders-bat[/link]