# Renaming files sequentially trough subfolders - .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do some renaming but recursively, below is where I am and I am a bit stuck. I added a remark where I think I'm wrong.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "rootfolder=%%i"

@echo on

cd %rootfolder%

for /r "%rootfolder%\" %%a in (*) do (
    set "folder=%%~dpa"
    cd %%~dpa
    for %%i in ("!folder!") do (
            set parent=%%~ni
        )

:: for %%i in ("!folder!") do (set parent=%%~ni) 
:: that part returns me parent= 
:: i would like it to be for example if folder is d:\test\test1 
:: parent = test1

    set /a count=10000
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "*.tif"') do (
        set /a count+=1
        set fileName=!parent!_!count:~-4!%%~xf
        rename "%%f" "!fileName!"
    )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Why don't you use delayed expansion for variable `folder`, like `!folder!`? And surround it in double-quotes rather than single-quotes (apostrophes), since the latter don't have any special meaning, except in `for /F` loops…

Comment: i tried this one ```for %%i in ("!folder!") do ( set parent=%%~ni )``` and changed ```set folder=%%~dpa``` but still parent is not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello,

posting an answer to my question, i managed to find a solution, you can see it below but i'm sure that right now the people like you who knows what they're doing have bleeding eyes.

so if you want to help me making that script look nicer, you're very welcome.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "rootfolder=%%i"

cd %rootfolder%

for /r "%rootfolder%" %%a in (*) do ( 
        set Fdir=%%~dpa 
        call :001 "%%~a"
)
    
:001
    cd %Fdir%
    set Fder=%cd%
    for %%i in (%Fder%) do (
        call :002 "%Fder%"
    )
    
:002
@echo on
set var1=%cd%
set var2=%var1%
set i=0

:003
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:+\+" %%A in ( "%var1%" ) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set var1=%%B
    goto 003
)
for /F "tokens=%i% delims=:+\+" %%G in ( "%var2%" ) do set last=%%G
goto 004

:004
    set parent=!last!
    set /a count=10000
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "*.tif"') do (
        set /a count+=1
        set fileName=!parent!_!count:~-4!%%~xf
        rename "%%f" "!fileName!"
    )
exit /b
```